# Can't extract cities of country OpenWeather

Tags: android, ios, react-native, openweathermap

I wanna use open-weather API for my application. for that i thought i might be able to save cities and their IDs in my own app in a json file and whenever i user wants a locations weather, app selects city's ID from json and make API call.

for that i downloaded a 30MB Json file provided by Openweather, it contains all countries and all theirs cities. putting a 30MB in my app isn't a good idea apparently. so i decided to extract my country cities only. but  the point is, this idea could not be done. so many cities from different countries has same names. and extracted json was huge again. even some coutry codes are cities in other countries.

i wonder if there is a way better implementation. or any idea or way to extract just cities of a country.

any help to implement weather call in my app for different cities would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but I recently bumped into this problem too. The way I ended up doing it was making `city.list.json` in to a default exported JSON object and writing a node script to then strip cities out by country code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var cityList = require('./city.list.js');

let output = {};
let countryCodes = [];

cityList.forEach((city) => {
  const country = city.country;
  if (country) {
    if (!countryCodes.includes(country)) {
      countryCodes.push(country);
    }
    if (!output[country]) {
      output[country] = [];
    }
    output[country].push({
      id: city.id,
      name: city.name,
    });
  }
});

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(output)) {
  const fileName = 'city.' + key.toLowerCase() + '.json';
  fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(value), function (err) {
    if (err) console.error(err.message);
    console.log(fileName + ' - saved!');
  });
}

fs.writeFile('countrycodes.json', JSON.stringify(countryCodes), function (err) {
  if (err) console.error(err.message);
  console.log('countrycodes.json' + ' - saved!');
});
```

This totally worked! Only problem I then ran into is `city.list.json` includes country names, and they are not differentiated in the data...